# How to created nested object using apache spark with python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Im having trouble creating a nested object using apache spark with python.

I have the following dataframe:

```
dataWithGps
root
 |-- vehicle_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- organization_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp_gps: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- diagnostic_trouble_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gps: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- lat: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- long: double (nullable = true)
```

And I want to trasnform it so it has the following schema:

```
nestedData
root
 |-- organization_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- timestamp_gps: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- vehicles: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- vehicle_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- gps: struct(nullable = true)
```

I have the following code to do it but isn't working as I'd expect:

```
    nestedFullDataRow = dataWithGps.groupby("organization_id", "vehicle_id", "timestamp_gps", "start_time").agg(F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col("timestamp_gps"))).alias("data")) \
        .groupBy("vehicle_id").agg(F.collect_list(struct(F.col("vehicle_id"))).alias("vehicles"))
    nestedFullDataRow.printSchema()
```

I am receiving the following schema unexpectedly:

```
root
 |-- vehicle_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vehicles: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- vehicle_id: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use transformations such as the following:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn(
        "data",
        F.array(
          F.struct(
            F.col("timestamp_gps"),
            F.array(
              F.struct(F.col("vehicle_id"), F.col("gps"))
            ).alias("vehicles")
          )
        )
      )
```

and drop the other columns which you deem unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

The following ended up working for me.

```
    nestedVehicles = dataWithGps.groupby("organization_id", "start_time", "vehicle_id", "timestamp_gps").agg(F.collect_list(
            F.struct(F.col("vehicle_id"), F.col("vehicle_label"), F.col("gps"), F.col("addons"), F.col("diagnostic_trouble_code"))
    ).alias("vehicles"))

    print()
    print("nestedVehicles")
    nestedVehicles.printSchema()
    print(nestedVehicles.head(3))

    nestedByTime = nestedVehicles.groupby("organization_id", "start_time").agg(F.collect_list(
        F.struct(F.col("timestamp_gps").alias("time"), F.col("vehicles"))
    ).alias("data"))

    print()
    print("nestedByTime")
    nestedByTime.printSchema()
    print(nestedByTime.head(3))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).